# Is there a keyboard shortcut in TRACE32 to start writing commands?

Tags: trace32

Is there a keyboard shortcut to put the cursor in the command field to directly start writing the command. Currently, I must use the mouse to put the cursor in the command field.

Answer (score 2):

By hitting the **Pause** key on your keyboard, the cursor will always jump to the command line of TRACE32 PowerView (no matter where the cursor has been before).

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with "Pause" key. I tried the both the media player Pause key and the debugger pause key but none caused the cursor to go to the command line.

Comment: The Pause key is on a normal US PC keyboard, in the top right corner, right to the Scroll key and above the PageUp key.
https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/pausekey.htm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key
Do you use a US keyboard? Or maybe a Laptop keyboard? Or maybe an Apple device?

Comment: OK. Now I understand. I'm using `Logitech Ergo K860` keyboard with a loptop. Nether the keyboard or the laptop's keyboard has this `Pause` key. Is there a work-around?

Comment: After some trials I found that just hitting the space key puts the cursor into the command line field. Thanks

Comment: Well, in most cases you can simply start typing, and it will be written to the command line. However, if the cursor is in some edit field or the internal editor, you'll need the `Pause` key. I don't think there is an alternative.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that I can simply start typing. I thought I had to press something to activate the command line field first. It turned out it is much simpler that I thought. Thanks